# Delete uploaded picture from a folder

Tags: php, html, image, upload

Hello I got this php code that saves image to a folder called "upload" and the picture is saved as a session. But after the picture is saved as a session, I want to delete it from the folder...
I don't know how.
Please help :)

```
  //something.php
 <?php 
  session start();
 $filename    = $_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"];
$destination = "upload/" . $_FILES["picture"]["name"]; 
move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination);

$_SESSION['picture'] = $destination;
  ?>
```

And here's my html form :

```
<form action="something.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you want to delete it? The picture isn't being stored in the session, only the path to the file is.

Comment: unlink($_SESSION['picture']); # see http://php.net/manual/function.unlink.php

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving the image data to the session, only the path of the file. So deleting the "file" will remove the data from the server, which I assume you don't want to do. But if you did, you'd do it like this:

`unlink($destination)`

or

`unlink($_SESSION['picture'])`

It properly isn't a good idea to store image data in a $_SESSION variable, and you should likely save it to your server somewhere where you can keep it.